# Keys in Spark Structured stream do not expire after completion of 'GroupStateTimeout.ProcessingTimeTimeout()'

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm writing a code for Structured streaming where I subscribe data from a Kafka queue and write this raw data back to Hbase. Between this transaction I have to fulfill following requirement,

1. Data from the stream must be de-duplicated for a window of 2 hours, i.e. whenever a data with new key comes in  the key should stay in memory for 2 hours and all duplicate data within those 2 hours must not be sent to Hbase.
2. If a new record for a key comes in where key is already in state but the value is changed, then such updated record should be sent to Hbase and the key should remain in memory for 2 hours after this point
3. There is no way to determine how late the data might arrive, and any data that comes in will satisfy any of the above conditions.

Due to conditions 2 & 3 I cannot use de-duplication provided by spark out of the box as applying a watermark will drop data older than it which violates condition 3.

So to solve this I have employed 'Arbitrary statefull processing'
REF: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html?_sm_au_=iVV0QDHnqrDVFDRMkpQ8jKtB7ckcW#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.GroupState

My code is as below:

**Code to read from kafka**

```
  val kafkaIpStream = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBroker)
      .option("subscribe", topic)
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
      .load()
```

**Code to De-duplicate**

```
    val kafkaStream = kafkaIpStream.selectExpr("cast (key as String)", "cast (value as String)")
      .withColumn("ts", split($"key", "/")(1))
      .selectExpr("key as rowkey", "ts", "value as val")
      .withColumn("isValid", validationUDF($"rowkey", $"ts", $"val"))
      .as[inputTsRecord]
      .groupByKey(_.rowkey)
      .flatMapGroupsWithState(OutputMode.Update(), GroupStateTimeout.ProcessingTimeTimeout())(updateStateAccrossRecords)
      .toDF("rowkey", "ts", "val", "isValid")
```

**De-duplication function**

```
case class inputTsRecord(rowkey: String, ts: String, `val`: String, isValid: String)
  case class state(rowkey: String, `val`: String, insertTimestamp: Long)

  def updateStateAccrossRecords(rowKey: String, inputRows: Iterator[inputTsRecord], oldState: GroupState[state]): Iterator[inputTsRecord] = {

    inputRows.toSeq.toIterator.flatMap { iprow =>

      println("received data for " + iprow.rowkey)

      if (oldState.hasTimedOut) {

          println("State timed out")

          oldState.remove()
          Iterator()
        }
      else if (oldState.exists) {

        println("State exists for " + iprow.rowkey)

          val timeDuration=((((System.currentTimeMillis / 1000)-oldState.get.insertTimestamp)/60)/60) 

          println("State not timed out for " + iprow.rowkey)


          println("Duration passed " + timeDuration)

          val updatedState = state(iprow.rowkey, iprow.`val`, (System.currentTimeMillis / 1000))
          val isValChanged = if (updatedState.`val` == oldState.get.`val`) false  else true

          if (isValChanged) {

            println("value changed for " + iprow.rowkey)
            oldState.update(updatedState)
            oldState.setTimeoutDuration("2 hours")

            Iterator(iprow)
          } else {
            if (timeDuration >= 2)
            {
               println("removing state for " + iprow.rowkey)
              oldState.remove()
            }
             println("value not changed for " + iprow.rowkey)
            Iterator()
          }



      } else {

        println("State does not exists for " + iprow.rowkey)

        val newState = state(iprow.rowkey, iprow.`val`, (System.currentTimeMillis / 1000))
        oldState.update(newState)
        oldState.setTimeoutDuration("2 hours")

        Iterator(iprow)
      }

    }
  }
```

Now the problem is this:

1. Even after specifying timeout as processing timeout of 2 hours the
   key does not expire after specified time [checked via logs].
2. The Key is unique i.e. ideally there will be only 1 entry for the
   key for entire lifetime of the application unless there is a
   duplicate.
3. Due to this the state ends up containing all the keys which will
   lead to memory issues as the stream progresses.
4. The key is only expiring when it receives data after 2 hours of its
   arrival due to below code

```
 if (timeDuration >= 2){
               println("removing state for " + iprow.rowkey)
              oldState.remove()
            }
```

5. The stream is receiving continuous data.

Form what I understand ones I use *GroupStateTimeout.ProcessingTimeTimeout()* on a stream the key should expire after the specified processing time of its arrival.

What am I missing?

Appreciate the help